# Right align controls inside second flex div

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to create a flex box layout consisting of two sets of buttons with the second set right aligned.  I attempted to do this with a flex-box layout

```
flx{display:-webkit-flex}
.flx:first-child{-webkit-flex:1;background-color:silver;}
.flx:nth-child(2){-webkit-flex:4;background-color:yellow;text-align:right}
```

as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9z6ms7ku/1/) but it isn't giving the desired result.  I suspect my understanding of how flex should work leaves something to be desired. I'd be most grateful to anyone who might be able to put me on the right track,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flex layout is fine. It is the CSS selectors that are causing the problem. The `.flx:first-child` is targeting the first child of elements with `class="flx"` rather than what I suspect you want is the first descendent child of the element with `class="flx"`.

Updating to `.flx div:first-child` and `.flx div:nth-child(2)` which uses the CSS [descendent combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) to apply the style to the children elements of the `class="flx"` container. See example below:

```css
.flx {
  display: -webkit-flex
}
.flx div:first-child {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  background-color: silver;
}
.flx div:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-flex: 4;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<div class='flx'>
  <div>
    <button>One</button>
    <button>Two</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Three</button>
    <button>Four</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect!  Consider this a 10 upvotes endorsement :-)